# Optimization of SQL query with multiple if statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select different values of a table based on a parameter passed in.

I have code that works correctly, it is shown below.

```
declare @type as int
set @type = 3

if @type = 1
    select * from t
else if @type = 2
    select * from t WHERE theType = 2 or theType = 3
else if @type = 3
    select * from t where theType = 3
```

This works very well, however i want to get rid of the if statements if possible.

Is there any way to make this code have the same result, but run better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach might be Dynamic SQL. If the example we have is overly simplified then using `OR` logic (like in Tim's answers) could end up with a cached query plan that isn't good for the query being run. This does appear to be true as `@type = 1` returns all rows, and when it has a value of `3` it is filter to a single value. This means that the estimates for `1` and `3` will be very different.

This gives you something like this:

```
DECLARE @type int;
SET @type = 3;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM t' +
           CASE @type WHEN 1 THEN N';'
                      WHEN 2 THEN N' WHERE theType = 2 or theType = 3;'
                      WHEN 3 THEN N' WHERE theType = 3'
           END;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

*This is not to say that Tim's answer is wrong, but that you could end up with poor performance for certain values.`*

Comment: Not my downvote, but no catch-all answer can be complete without at least one of the following links: https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/ || https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/ || http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Comment: I do like Bertrand's "kitchen sink" analogy for them @ZoharPeled :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try rewriting this to be a single query:

```
select *
from t
where
    @type = 1 or
    (@type = 2 and theType in (2, 3)) or
    (@type = 3 and theType = 3);
```

I don't know if this would actually run faster than what you currently have, but it does get rid of the if statements.